# After migrating Rails 3 app from MySQL to PostgresSQL Solr fails to load with error: Could not start JMX monitoring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr

I migrated my rails 3.28 app to Postgres from MySQL.  The migration worked fine locally (on Mac) and rake sunspot:solr:start works fine, as did the reindex and searches.

However, when I deployed to my AWS instance running SOLR 5.4.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.  SOLR will not load.  Instead, in the admin dashboard I see

Log output

```
1081 INFO  (coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-2) [   ] o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Creating SolrCore 'uncat' using configuration from instancedir /mnt/ebs/solr/data/uncat
1081 INFO  (coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1) [   ] o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Creating SolrCore 'staging' using configuration from instancedir /mnt/ebs/solr/data/staging
1097 INFO  (coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-2) [   x:uncat] o.a.s.c.SolrCore solr.NRTCachingDirectoryFactory
1097 INFO  (coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1) [   x:staging] o.a.s.c.SolrCore solr.NRTCachingDirectoryFactory
1104 INFO  (coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-2) [   x:uncat] o.a.s.c.SolrCore [[uncat] ] Opening new SolrCore at [/mnt/ebs/solr/data/uncat], dataDir=[null]
1104 INFO  (coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1) [   x:staging] o.a.s.c.SolrCore [[staging] ] Opening new SolrCore at [/mnt/ebs/solr/data/staging], dataDir=[null]
1128 ERROR (coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1) [   x:staging] o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Error creating core [staging]: Could not start JMX monitoring 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not start JMX monitoring 
    at org.apache.solr.core.JmxMonitoredMap.<init>(JmxMonitoredMap.java:129)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initInfoRegistry(SolrCore.java:960)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:744)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:665)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:746)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:466)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:457)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor$1.run(ExecutorUtil.java:232)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot bind to URL [rmi://127.0.0.1:56411/vultest]: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; neste
d exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.newIOException(RMIConnectorServer.java:827)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:432)
    at org.apache.solr.core.JmxMonitoredMap.<init>(JmxMonitoredMap.java:124)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)]
    at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.bind(RegistryContext.java:161)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.bind(GenericURLContext.java:228)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:425)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.bind(RMIConnectorServer.java:644)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:427)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:623)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:343)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.bind(RegistryImpl_Stub.java:65)
    at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.bind(RegistryContext.java:155)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:556)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:452)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:229)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:617)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Are you sure Solr is running? That error message makes me think it's not really working

Comment: This question is also very unclear. You see an error in the "admin dashboard", but you give no indication what it is? Is it Rails? Solr? Something else?

Comment: the error is in the code block above.

Comment: @MikeSzyndel output of service solr status:
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/solr; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2024-02-14 16:23:31 EST; 28min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1354 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/solr start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 0B
      CPU: 0

Feb 14 16:23:25 stage3.esebco.com systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Controls Apache Solr as a Service...
Feb 14 16:23:25 stage3.esebco.com su[1389]: Successful su for solr by root
Feb 14 16:23:25 stage3.esebco.com su[1389]: + ??? root:solr
...

Comment: @dbugger I added the log output to the question, thanks.

Comment: Here's your problem `Cannot bind to URL [rmi://127.0.0.1:56411/vultest]: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; neste
d exception is: ` but I have no idea what that means since I don't work with Java